# Can arithmetic be performed in a mysql table

Tags: calculated-columns

Is there a way to automatically fill column3 with an arithmetic product in a mysql table when a numeric post is inserted in column1 and column2.

e.g.

`This is not the code but just a way of showing what I need

user inserted value in Column1  = 5

user inserted value in Column2  = 3

automatically inserted value in Column3  = 15`

Comment: So you want MySQL to do it via a trigger instead of doing it in the code which inserts or doing it in the code which reads from the database?

Comment: Yes, I want to post values for Column1 and Column2 and I want the Column3 to be populataed automatically in the mysql database

Comment: I'm not an expert at MySQL triggers, so the best I can do is point you to the [MySQL trigger documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html). I thought someone else would jump in with an answer.